# How to put a node on JavaCC stack manually?

Tags: java, javacc

I have a production rule like this:

```
void prod12() #void:
{}
{
  prod1() | prod2()
}

void prod1() :
{}{
...
}

void prod2() :
{}{
...
}
```

that is, `prod12()` does not produce a node, instead, it leaves nodes produced by `prod1()` or `prod2()`.
Now I want `prod2()` to be an ordinary function which produces a result (of type Expr), and I want to place that result on the stack as it was when `prod2()` were a production:`

```
void prod12() #void:
{Expr expr=null;}
{
  prod1() | expr=prod2()
}

void prod1() :
{}{
...
}

Expr prod2() {
... return expr;
}
```

What else should I do in order result of `prod2()` be placed on the node stack the same way as it was when `prod2()` was a production?

Comment: Did you try looking at the code generated for prod1? You might find the answer there.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

    `void prod12() #void:
    {Expr expr=null;}
    {
      prod1() | expr=prod2() {jjtree.pushNode(expr);}
    }`